# MDX: Dimensions used in combination cause slowness / locking conflicts

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I'm having a problem with an MDX query on SSAS which is running very slow:

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY
(
    [Measures].[Value]
) ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY
(
    [Dimension1].[Hierarchy1].[Level1].[Member1],
    [Dimension2].[Hierarchy2].[Level2],
    [Dimension3].[Hierarchy3].[Level3],
    [Dimension4].[Hierarchy4].[Level4]
) ON ROWS
FROM [RePro]
WHERE
(
    [Dimension5].[Hierarchy5].[Level5].[Member5]
)
```

This results in "*locking conflicts*" and is extremely slow. However, if I comment out any one of Dimension2, Dimension3 or Dimension4, it resolves the problem and it returns quickly albeit one of my dimensions missing from the results. What does this tell you about the underlying problem and how can I fix it? Is it something to do with dimensions not being in other dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
As the question was completely revised now, I removed my first answer.

Just some ideas what might cause the slow response and how you could remedy it:

- Maybe try to reduce the number of dimensions by putting more hierarchies into the same dimension. This enables AutoExists which should speed up the run time.
- If you can choose, put all hierarchies of the same dimension together in the ROWS (in case `Dimension1` to `Dimension4` are not all distinct.
- In case the restriction to one member of `[Dimension1].[Hierarchy1]` and/or `[Dimension5].[Hierarchy5]` happens frequently, consider partitioning the measure group by this hierarchy.
- Maybe properly designing aggregations could help.

Apart from this general advice, it is very difficult to answer to a question as general as yours. You dis not state anything about the size of your dimensions, the size of the measure group of `[Measures].[Value]`, if you have any many-to-many relationships involved, if your measure is calculated or a physical measure, the size of your server, etc.

Comment: Functionally, this is identical to my second code snippet which is already a Crossjoin within the `ON ROWS` clause. A Crossjoin can be specified with `*`-separated items, or comma-separated items within `(` and `)` (with or without the `Crossjoin` keyword). And your second set has a single item which is the same as specifiying it without the curly braces.

Comment: I have completely rejigged the question now as the cause of the problem appears to be nothing to do with what I first thought - the use of a set in the SELECT clause was a red herring. The problem I think is to do with the dimensions in the SELECT clause. I have rewritten the question accordingly.

Comment: Ah, just seen your revised Answer (didn't get a notification). This is still an ongoing issue at work, so I will be revisiting it soon, and I'll look into your suggestions then and get back to you. Thanks :)